# How to read XML data from a URL by using Visual Basic .NET and Windows Phone 7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I have this XML file located at http://www.example.com/sample_file.xml

```
<DataSet>
<Body>
<Day date="2011-08-29">
<Price type="Macy's">123.4</Price> 
<Price type="Tiffany's">456.7</Price> 
</Day>
</DataSet>
</Body>
```

Using VB.NET, I want to read the file from the web and display the information ('type' and 'price') in a TextBlock.

I would also like to get only the price for a single type (for example: Macy's).

Comment: you need to download the file, use the datacontractserializer to convert the data into a object, to use the data. there are tons of examples online.

Comment: you could also use LINQ to Xml on the downloaded file to query properties you want.

Comment: here is information on the DataContractSerializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just use LINQ to XML, its really Easy,

i have a link here, its in C# but you can quite easily write the same in VB.

[Building an XML based RSS Reader](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-windows)